# No output from Kaminari

Tags: kaminari

I'm  trying to paginate a model using kaminari (0.13.0), but I can't get the paginate helper to display anything.

In my view,

```
# show.haml
= paginate @jobs
# @jobs.class => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

I've generated a configuration file using `rails g kaminari:config` and default views using `rails g kaminari:views default`.

No errors are being displayed either.

**edit**

The output from some of the other helper methods:

```
# show.haml

= paginate @jobs
# no output

= link_to_previous_page @jobs, "Prev"
# undefined method `link_to_previous_page' for #<#<Class:0xb12818a4>:0xac737c4>

= link_to_next_page @jobs, "Next"
# no output

= page_entries_info @jobs
# Displaying <b>1</b> job
```

Comment: what will = debug @jobs gives. Does it have enough record to show pagination.

Comment: It prints out the models' attributes correctly. I should also mention that I was having the same trouble with will_paginate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectations were incorrect. I was expecting Kaminari to output `Prev 1 Next` in plain text when the `paginate` helper was called on a `ActiveRecord::Relation` with only one record. Adding more records, as suggested by DeathHammer, now correctly outputs the `nav`.

Comment: Kaminari also seems to not produce any output if you only have one page worth of records.